# Rails Observer not passing arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

Trying to set up a model observer. AuditTrail is triggered however it's not passing the values. Why?

```
  def after_update(stock)
    AuditTrail.create(message: 'Stock update: #{stock.in_stock} * #{stock.variation.name}|#{stock.color.name} in #{stock.storage.name}',
                  importance: 'Success')
 end
```

Comment: Are the single quotes typing errors in the question? If you have them in your code as well, you probably meant double quotes, otherwise it doesn't matter what triggers the after_update, the AuditTrail record will always be the same.

Comment: Glad you found it. Silly single quotes error. Thanks a lot. If you add an answer I can flag it as The One so you get all the credit :)

Comment: Simple syntax problems should not get too much attention :) It's probably better to just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @eugen should have used double quotes.